# Module not found: Error: Cannot find file: 'node-jquery.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\node_modules\jquery\lib\jQuery'

Tags: jquery, reactjs

hello I m trying to run a simple react code  I have a problem in [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Xhk.png)jquery  I have uploaded here  index.js and package.jason and the query error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csUUv.png)

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.